# print each level in BFS

Tags: ruby, breadth-first-search

So, i can traverse the list, but i can't print out each level. Not sure how.

I have something like this:

```
$list = {
  "A" => ["C","D","E"],
  "B" => ["C","F"],
  "C" => ["A","B","D","F","E"],
  "D" => ["A","C","E"],
  "E" => ["A","C","D"],
  "F" => ["B","C"]
 }


def BFS2()
  queue = ["A"]
  visited = {"A"=>true}
  print "A "
    while(!queue.empty?)
      node = queue.pop()
      $list[node].each do |child|
        if visited[child] != true then
           print "#{child} "
           queue.push(child)
           visited[child] = true
         end
      end
    end
end
```

instead of print it like

```
A C D E B F
```

id like to print it as so

```
A
C D E
B F
```

I've tried a few different things, but i can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution required checking to see if you'd actually printed something for a given node so that we didn't add an extra `\n` for nodes that shouldn't have printed anything.

#### Solution

We add the appropriate `\n`'s as needed.

```
def BFS2()
  queue = ["A"]
  visited = {"A"=>true}
  puts "A "
    while(!queue.empty?)
      do_print = false
      node = queue.pop()
      $list[node].each do |child|
        if visited[child] != true then
           print "#{child} "
           queue.push(child)
           visited[child] = true
           do_print = true
        end
      end
      if do_print == true
        print "\n "
      end
    end
end
```